# What is the pythonic way to add type information to an object's attributes?

Tags: python, types

I'm building classes where I know the intended types of the attributes, but Python of course doesn't. While it's un-pythonic to want to tell it, supposing I *do* want to, is there an idiomatic way to do so?

Why: I'm reading in foreign-format data (without type information) involving objects-nested-inside-objects. It's easy to put it into nested dictionaries, but I want it in objects of my class-types, to get the right behaviours as well as the data. For instance: suppose my class `Book` has an attribute `isbn` which I will fill with an `ISBNumber` object. My data gives me the isbn as a string; I would like to be able to look at `Book` and say "That field should be filled by `ISBNumber(theString)`."

Bonus glee for me if the solution can be applied to classes I get from someone else without editing their code.

(I'm restricted to 2.6, although interested in solutions for 3.x if they exist.)

Comment: Does it involve slapping someone with a fish?

Comment: Does pickle not work for this - even if not its source code would vae type information

Comment: My problem is reading, not writing, and reading a (textual) serialisation format I don't control (which doesn't include type info). Pickle (I presume) stores all the type info it needs to unpickle (module and class names).

Comment: It sounds like you are parsing a foreign format rather than serializing a Python object. A bit of example data would clear that up.

Comment: @msw: thanks, good point, it is foreign format rather than serialised (edited Q to match). No example data because it happens to be xml and I don't want to hear about xml-specific solutions.

Comment: "but Python of course doesn't"?  What? All objects have a type.  What are you trying to do?  Attributes are just names, and don't have a type until an object is actually assigned -- objects have types.  Usually we write these things in docstrings.

Comment: @S.Lott: edited to "where I know the *intended* types of the attributes", is that clearer?

I'm aware that attributes don't *have* types, that's the problem I'm trying to solve: I have an attribute (just a name) and some data (just a string) and *I* know that the right way to put them together is to use the string in a particular constructor (say, ISBNumber for the isbn attribute of Book) to get the value to store in the attribute. I'm looking for a pythonic way to store (and use) that association: things-to-go-in-isbn for Book objects should be ISBNumbers.

Comment: Have you tried an xml-specific solution? I'll tell ya, customers and their requirements ;)

Comment: @Tikitu: Are you talking about an ORM mapping where types REALLY matter? (because of the RDBMS limitations)  Or are you talking about a pure Python class where the phrase "intended type" barely has a sensible meaning.  Since "string" could be `str` or `unicode` or any duck type class that's functionally equivalent.  What actual problem do you have?  Remembering what a class is supposed to do?

Comment: @S.Lott: Pure python, with I think a pythonic meaning for "intended type". I intend the isbn attribute to be filled with something that quacks like an ISBNumber (with methods str doesn't have, like ...I don't know... checksum_is_valid()). What I get from the data is just a string. Sure I don't care about the precise type, but I do care that it quacks the right way. Strings (of any type) don't.

I think you're missing what my *actual* problem is (maybe because I phrase the question, already, unpythonically), and chewing me out for basic misunderstandings that I don't, in fact, suffer from.

Comment: @msw: not to complicate things, but eventually I'd like to use the same notions --ideally the same code-- with *several* external formats. Plus, I want to understand how I should be thinking about this in python, without getting bogged down in which xml-handling modules can do what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve something like this. If coupling the input format to your object model is acceptable then you could use descriptors to create type adaptors:

```
class TypeAdaptingProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, key, type_, factory=None):
        self.key = key
        self.type_ = type_
        if factory is None:
            self.factory = type_

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return getattr(instance, self.key)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.type_):
            value = self.factory(value)
        setattr(instance, self.key, value)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        delattr(instance, self.key)

class Book(object):
    isbn = TypeAdaptingProperty('isbn_', ISBNNumber)

b = Book()
b.isbn = 123 # Does the equivalent of b.isbn = ISBNNumber(123)
```

However if you don't fully control the message structure, such coupling isn't a good idea. In such cases I like to use the interpreter pattern to adapt input messages to output types. I create a small framework that enables me to build declarative object structures to process the input data.

The framework may look something like this:

```
class Adaptor(object):
    """Any callable can be an adaptor. This base class just proxies calls
    to an appropriately named method."""
    def __call__(self, input):
        return self.adapt(input)

class ObjectAdaptor(Adaptor):
    """Adaptor to create objects adapting the input value to the
    factory function/constructor arguments, and optionally setting
    fields after construction."""
    def __init__(self, factory, args=(), kwargs={}, fields={}):
        self.factory = factory
        self.arg_adaptors = args
        self.kwarg_adaptors = kwargs
        self.field_adaptors = fields

    def adapt(self, input):
        args = (adaptor(input) for adaptor in self.arg_adaptors)
        kwargs = dict((key, adaptor(input)) for key,adaptor in self.kwarg_adaptors.items())
        obj = self.factory(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, adaptor in self.field_adaptors.items():
            setattr(obj, key, adaptor(input))
        return obj

def TypeWrapper(type_):
    """Converts the input to the specified type."""
    return ObjectAdaptor(type_, args=[lambda input:input])

class ListAdaptor(Adaptor):
    """Converts a list of objects to a single type."""
    def __init__(self, item_adaptor):
        self.item_adaptor = item_adaptor
    def adapt(self, input):
        return map(self.item_adaptor, input)

class Pick(Adaptor):
    """Picks a key from an input dictionary."""
    def __init__(self, key, inner_adaptor):
        self.key = key
        self.inner_adaptor = inner_adaptor
    def adapt(self, input):
        return self.inner_adaptor(input[self.key])
```

The message adaptors look something like this:

```
book_message_adaptor = ObjectAdaptor(Book, kwargs={
    'isbn': Pick('isbn_number', TypeWrapper(ISBNNumber)),
    'authors': Pick('authorlist', ListAdaptor(TypeWrapper(Author)))
})
```

Notice that the message structure names might not be the same as the object model.

Message processing itself looks like this:

```
message = {'isbn_number': 123, 'authorlist': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}
book = book_message_adaptor(message)
# Does the equivalent of:
# Book(isbn=ISBNNumber(message['isbn_number']),
#      authors=map(Author, message['author_list']))
```

Comment: The Adaptor framework: niiiice. Expect this is probably *the* answer; having too-hastily accepted one already, I'll leave it a day or so to be sure. (Still finding my way with StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 1):

That's - in principle, at least - what an object's `__repr__` function is supposed to enable: the unambiguous reconstruction of an object.

If your class is defined like:

```
class ISBN(object):
    def __init__(self, isbn):
        self.isbn = isbn

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'ISBN(%r)' % self.isbn
```

Then you are one `eval` away from reconstituting your original object. See also the [pickle module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Riffing on the ISBN class then gives you a book class

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, author, isbn):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.isbn = isbn

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Book(%r, %r, %r)' % (self.title, self.author, self.isbn)

good_book = Book("Cat's Cradle", 'Kurt Vonnegut, Jr.', ISBN('038533348X'))
bad_book = Book('The Carpetbaggers', 'Harold Robbins', ISBN('0765351463'))
library = [good_book, bad_book]
print library
# => [Book("Cat's Cradle", 'Kurt Vonnegut, Jr.', ISBN('038533348X')), 
      Book('The Carpetbaggers', 'Harold Robbins', ISBN('0765351463'))]
reconstruct = eval(str(library))
print reconstruct
# => [Book("Cat's Cradle", 'Kurt Vonnegut, Jr.', ISBN('038533348X')),
      Book('The Carpetbaggers', 'Harold Robbins', ISBN('0765351463'))]
```

Of course your objects might do more than just construct and reconstruct themselves... and the caveat about eval that Tamás noted.

Comment: I don't control <i>writing</i> the serialisation data, only <i>reading</i> it. Sadly. (The Book data might not even have been produced from Python, e.g. someone else's xml data-access API.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have already considered the `pickle` module and it is not suitable for your purposes. In that case, you can attach an attribute to your class that specifies the type for each attribute:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _types = {"isbn": ISBNNumber}
```

Upon reconstruction, you iterate over `_types` and try to enforce the type:

```
for name, type_name in MyClass._types.iteritems():
    if hasattr(obj, name):
        value = getattr(obj, name)
        if not isinstance(value, type_name):
            setattr(obj, name, type_name(value))
```

In the code sample above, `obj` is the object being reconstructed and I assume that the attributes are already assigned in a string format (or whatever you get from unserialisation).

If you want this to work with third-party classes where you cannot alter the source code, you can attach the `_types` attribute to the class at run-time after having imported it from somewhere else. For instance:

```
>>> from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
>>> cp = ConfigParser()
>>> cp._types
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: ConfigParser instance has no attribute '_types'
>>> ConfigParser._types = {"name": "whatever"}
>>> cp._types
{"name": "whatever"}
```

I also agree with using `__repr__` and `eval` if you have *full control* over what you will get from your input files; however, if any user input is involved, using `eval` leads to the possibility of arbitrary code execution, which is quite dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, that'll do it I think. Pickle and repr/eval are no good because I'm reading foreign-format data (as msw pointed out, sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Argh, too quick to accept (still finding my way with StackOverflow). Another answer solves the nesting problem (if ISBNumber was a complex class with attributes itself) with a more complicated framework. Now (chastened) I'll leave it a day or so before deciding.

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps not exactly what you want but the [Enthought traits API](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/documentation.php) does give you an ability to add explicit typing to Python class attributes. It might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's two very nice libraries for this:

1. [atom](https://github.com/nucleic/atom)
2. [traitlets](https://github.com/ipython/traitlets)

They both allow you to restrict attributes to a specific type and provide means of notification when an attribute changes.

```
from atom.api import Atom, Unicode, Range, Bool, observe
class Person(Atom):
    """ A simple class representing a person object.

    """
    last_name = Unicode()

    first_name = Unicode()

    age = Range(low=0)

    debug = Bool(False)
```